# Bug in extension: getting background page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

For my extension, I have `popup.html` and `background.html`. In the background, I listen to `window.online` event and `chrome.runtime.reload()` when the internet connection comes back. However, while the popup is open if the internet goes offline and online, only the background page is reloaded while popup stays the same. Then, a `TypeError` occurs from the below part

```
  apiFunctions.setHandleRequest('getBackgroundPage', function() {
    return GetExtensionViews(-1, 'BACKGROUND')[0] || null;
  });
```

GetExtensionViews(-1, 'BACKGROUND') returns `undefined`, so it tries to access `undefined[0]`. Why is this happening and how would I be able to solve this problem?

Comment: Please open a new issue at http://crbug.com/new.

Comment: You are killing the connection between background and popup by reloading. Instead just reload the popup. I do that with an extension.

Comment: Someone has reported this bug at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=384726

Answer (score 2):

The best way to handle what you are doing is to not handle the online/offline in your content script.  The problem with handling such events in your content script is that in your background script you are doing a reload.  Once you do a reload, all content scripts are unable to communicate with the backend.  For example,

Once you reload if you do a `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` from the content script to the backend it will throw an error that it is unable to communicate with backend.  This will occur until the tab is refreshed.

Because you seem to be doing reloads so often, it is probably better to

1. Re-inject the content script into all open tabs upon reload.  Example, backend code that will read your manifest and re-inject all content scripts.  These new content scripts can talk to your backend.  Just make sure if they are inserting any DOM or CSS that you remove the old DOM or CSS so you don't end up with duplicate elements in a page which will be a user interface bug.

   ```
   function isSafeToInjectTo(tabs, i) {
       if (!tabs[i].url) return false;

       var httpOrHttps = tabs[i].url.indexOf('http://') !== -1 ||  tabs[i].url.indexOf('https://') !== -1;
       if (!httpOrHttps) return false;

       var googleWebstoreSite = tabs[i].url.indexOf('https://chrome.google.com/webstore') !== -1;
       if (googleWebstoreSite) return false;

       return true;
   }
   //THIS CODE SHOULD BE PLACED IN BACKGROUND PAGE AND WILL ONLY RUN ONCE WHEN BACKGROUND     SCRIPT STARTS
   console.log('injecting ');
   var js = [];
   var css = [];
   chrome.runtime.getManifest().content_scripts.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
       $.each(element.js, function (i, el) {
           if ($.inArray(el, js) === -1) js.push(el);
       });
       $.each(element.css, function (i, el) {
           if ($.inArray(el, css) === -1) css.push(el);
       });
   })
   chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) {
       for (var i in tabs) {
           //not able to inject into chrome:// or other non web pages and on google web store - extension has restrictions
           if (isSafeToInjectTo(tabs, i)) {
               //RE INJECT ALL JS
               for (var s in js) {
                   chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, {file: js[s]});
               }
               //RE INJECT ALL CSS
               for (var c in css) {
                   chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tabs[i].id, {file: css[c]}); 
              }
           }
       }
   });
   ```
2. Do not reload upon online/offline and instead handle online/offline in your XHR requests and just set a short timer loop `setTimeout()`/`setInterval()` to retry or use a framework to handle this for you.

Comment: The question had nothing to do with content scripts. It's about a popup.